# How to handle a large number of strings using java?

Tags: java, string

The processing of each string is: ***split*** => ***encrypt some fields*** => ***remove some fields*** => ***merge***.

- First of all, this process of splitting and merging is extremely time-consuming. Can it be processed in batches or not split or other algorithms exist?
- Secondly, when the data is transmitted, it is `byte[]`, and it needs to be converted to `String` during processing, and it must be converted back to `byte[]` after being merged(*Of course, the encryption process also needs to be converted to `byte[]`*).Is there a way to split `byte[]` with specific characters like `String#split()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Use parallel stream? If you'd show some code, could give an example

Comment: depending on string structure, and how much you actually want to optimize, I'd give a finite automaton a thought; singlepass + data locality should give decent benefit. But it's much more hurdle to implement than using standard lib like String.split, so you really would have to think if you want to bother with such approach

Comment: I think the optimization point should be on a single piece of data, rather than using parallel streams @Ward

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you input is a `Collection<String>`, you can probably benefit from a [`parallelStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream())

```
Collection<String> output = input.parallelStream()
    .map(processString())
    .collect(toList());
```